# store images in FTP and path in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, ftp

I am doing image gallery for website but admin want to upload image by him self, so i have prepared this code to transfer images from website to FTP.

But some of them are telling you have to store images path in database then you have to take it from mysql and display / delete / upload images on website.

Since i am new bee in PHP i am not able to do that, so any one can help me with this issue ,... Thanx in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input name="file" type="file" /><br><br>
<input name="file1" type="file" /><br><br>
<input name="file2" type="file" /><br><br>

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$ftp_server = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";  
$ftp_user_name = "xxxxxxxxxxx";  
$ftp_user_pass = "xxxxxxxxx";  

$folder = "/www/imagetest/123/";

$source_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$source_file1 = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
$source_file2 = $_FILES['file2']['tmp_name'];

$destination_file = $folder . $_FILES['file']['name'];
$destination_file1 = $folder . $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$destination_file2 = $folder . $_FILES['file2']['name'];

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "FTP connection has failed!";
    echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
    exit; 
} else {
    echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 
$upload1 = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file1, $source_file1, FTP_BINARY); 
$upload2 = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file2, $source_file2, FTP_BINARY);


// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 
echo "FTP upload 1 has failed!\n";
} else {
echo "1 Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file\n";
}

if (!$upload1) { 
echo "FTP upload 2 has failed!\n";
} else {
echo "2 Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file\n";
}

if (!$upload2) { 
echo "FTP upload 3 has failed!\n";
} else {
echo "3 Uploaded $source_file to $ftp_server as $destination_file\n";
}
// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: `ftp` is a long outdated protocol of the 70th. Everyone can snoop your login credentials since it does not provide any form of encryption and it is a nightmare for all network administrator. Consider moving to a more modern replacement: ftps or better sftp

Comment: What you are talking about doing is not the same as the code above. The code above shows you are trying to FTP images based on a PHP $_POST, but there is nothing about connecting to a database. Furthermore, why not just have your admin post his files to an FTP folder, then use PHP script to loop through the filenames instead of involving the database?